# How can I output content from an asset in a view?

Tags: php, symfony

My Symfony2 app creates an HTML file on the server machine which is then sent to wkhtmltopdf to generate a CSS file from it. This HTML file is also accessible via the browser.

The CSS/JS paths in the file are given using the Symfony assets view helper like so:

```
<link href="<?php echo $view['assets']->getUrl('bundles/mybundle/css/style.css') ?>" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

This works fine when viewing the file in the browser. However, when I hand the file to wkhtmltopdf the paths are no longer correct as wkhtmltopdf operates on the filesystem and not via the webserver (which it could not access correctly anyway).

Therefore instead of linking the CSS file I am looking for a way to embed it into the HTML file so that all the CSS is contained in the file and wkhtmltopdf does not need to look for a CSS file.

How can I tell Symfony to output an asset file's content instead of its link right into a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround I have found is to read the file in the controller and then pass the contents to the view.

So in the controller you have

```
    $styleFiles = [
        "bundles/mybundle/css/style.css",
        "bundles/mybundle/css/print.css"
    ];

    $style = "";

    foreach ($styleFiles as $file) {
        $style .= file_get_contents($this->get("kernel")->getRootDir() . "/../web/" . $file);
    }
```

Now you just need to add an output for this in the view:

```
<style type="text/css">
    <?= $style ?>
</style>
```